# Minecraft Forge Modding, handling and calling sound events question

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

trying to make a combat music mod for minecraft forge 1.20.1 similar to like genshin impact, basically, a battle music sound will play everytime the player will get hit by a hostile entity/mob and the battle music will stop if there are no hostile mobs within 15 blocks , [problem is with my current code, the detection for if the player is attacked and the method for playing the music is working (as per the logger messages) but no music plays when the player is attacked

Explanation of each code block:
the onAttack method checks if the player getting attacked is an instance of player and checks the world difficulty if its not in peaceful otherwise if the amount of hostile mobs is greater than 0 the playCustomSound method is called

```
@SubscribeEvent
    public void onAttack(final LivingAttackEvent event) {
        LivingEntity entity = event.getEntity();
        if (entity instanceof LocalPlayer player) {
            Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getInstance();
            SoundManager manager = mc.getSoundManager();
            if (mc.level != null && mc.level.getDifficulty() != Difficulty.PEACEFUL) {
                int hostileMobs = getEntities(player);

                LOGGER.info("Hostile Mobs Nearby: " + hostileMobs);

                if (hostileMobs > 0) {
                    if (!manager.isActive(lastSound)) {
                        LOGGER.info("Attempting to play custom sound");
                        playCustomSound(); // Call the custom method to play the sound
                        decaySeconds = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    LOGGER.info("No hostile mobs nearby");
                    // If there are no hostile mobs within 15 blocks, stop the sound
                    if (manager.isActive(lastSound)) {
                        LOGGER.info("Stopping the custom sound");
                        manager.stop(lastSound);
                        lastSound = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I can confirm this works from my logs I can see the logger messages "Attempting to play custom sound" and Hostile Mobs Nearby:"

getEntities method also works since I can see the correct logger messages

```
    private int getEntities(LocalPlayer player) {
        return player.clientLevel.getEntitiesOfClass(Monster.class, new AABB(-12D, -10D, -12D, 12D, 10D, 12D).move(player.getX(), player.getY(), player.getZ()), mob -> mob.canAttack(player)).size();
    }
```

issue lies here where I call the UNIV_BRAWL sound event from ModSounds class I can confirm that the UNIV_BRAWL sound event is registered correctly since I can play the sound using /playsound command and works fine

```
   private void playCustomSound() {
        Minecraft mc = Minecraft.getInstance();
        SoundManager manager = mc.getSoundManager();

        // Replace with your registered SoundEvent
        SoundEvent soundEvent = ModSounds.UNIV_BRAWL.get();

        if (soundEvent == null) {
            LOGGER.error("SoundEvent is null. Make sure it's properly registered.");
            return;
        }

        ResourceLocation soundLocation = soundEvent.getLocation();
        LOGGER.info("Attempting to play sound: " + soundLocation.toString());



        SimpleSoundInstance soundInstance = SimpleSoundInstance.forMusic(soundEvent);
        manager.play(soundInstance);
    }
```

**here is a snippet of the ModSounds class **
the ModSounds class registers the sound event UNIV_BRAWL and specifies the resource location battlemusic.MOD_ID UNIV_BRAWL

```
    public static final DeferredRegister<SoundEvent> SOUNDS = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.SOUND_EVENTS, "battlemusic");

    public static final RegistryObject<SoundEvent> UNIV_BRAWL = SOUNDS.register(
            "combatmusic", () -> SoundEvent.createVariableRangeEvent(new ResourceLocation(battlemusic.MOD_ID, "univ_brawl")));



    public static void register(IEventBus eventBus) {
        SOUNDS.register(eventBus);
    }

}
```

my main class for calling the other classes when the mod is loaded

```
@Mod("battlemusic")
public class battlemusic {
    public static final String MOD_ID = "battlemusic";
    public static final Logger LOGGER = LogUtils.getLogger();

    public int decaySeconds = 0;
    public SimpleSoundInstance lastSound;

    public battlemusic() {
        IEventBus modEventBus = FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus();

        ModCreativeModTabs.register(modEventBus);
        ModItems.register(modEventBus);
        ModSounds.register(modEventBus);

        modEventBus.addListener(this::commonSetup);
        modEventBus.addListener(this::addCreative);

        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
    }

    private void commonSetup(final FMLCommonSetupEvent event) {
        // Add your common setup code here
    }

    private void addCreative(BuildCreativeModeTabContentsEvent event) {
        if (event.getTabKey() == CreativeModeTabs.INGREDIENTS) {
            // Add your creative tab contents here
        }
    }
```

any help/insights can be really helpful

play the sound event "UNIV_BRAWL" everytime the player gets hit or recieves damage from a hostile entity/mob

Comment: Have you checked that the volume of the sound is not zero by default or that there isn't a duration parameter missing?

Comment: yes I am sure that my sounds are not muted or set to 0,  and I think I have no need for the duration parameter since the sound will stop if there are no more hostile entities within 15 blocks, I'm trying to replicate genshin impact's combat music

Comment: figured it out, modid mismatch on gradle settings